# referencing the thirteenth month in formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any way I can access the 13th month (the roll up from closing) I have report parameters set to the 12th month as everything goes to zero in the 13th month for the other accounts (as it should) but I can't access the rollup amounts which aren't done until the 13th month.

Comment: So you want the roll up to happen in the end of the 12th month right?

Comment: yes. I need to capture the data for the one account but everything else I can capture in the 12t month. I was thinking of changing some of the formulas and running it in the 13th but changing the formulas of the other accounts to select the 12th so that they would still have a balance. Would that be what I should do or is there another option?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: No. I was asking if I could access the 13th month. Being new to xi I thought you might know as I did not. I had a plan of attack for either answer, that's all I am looking for. I know I can change the code backwards as I have worked on enough to see if it worked. But if I could do the reverse, just write something to access data in the 13th month I'd be good. I'm guessing that I cannot as it is "going to a future date".